# How to insert and show element inserted in panel with extjs

Tags: extjs, insert, panel, tabpanel

I want insert new a element in panel, the insert is good but hide.
If I want show my update I can change the current panel of tabpanel and rewind into my panel modified...

I search to view directly my update (directshow) ...
please help ;-)

PS : Sorry for my bad english practice.

Hervé

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you exactly want to do, but I think you are looking for `panel.doLayout()`.